# Are Goblin Vs. Gnomes and Curse Of Naxxramas gone?

Tags: hearthstone

I discovered that some time ago **Heathstone** had two adventures that are "gone" from the game, **Goblin Vs. Gnomes** and **Curse Of Naxxramas**. *Blizzard* removed those adventures, and, from what I read and what I think I understood, those adventures are now the **Whispers of the Old Gods** expansion.

I have some questions about this.

1. Could people who bought those adventures have cards that do not exist in the **Whispers of the Old Gods** expansion? (which could create an  advantage for those users.)
2. The **Whispers of the Old Gods** is free, right?. I mean that when we refer to the term "expansion" we are just refering to the collectible card-packs of **Whispers of the Old Gods**, or is there something else comprising this expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, only Naxxramas is an adventure, Goblins vs. Gnomes is an expansion. The former provides several challenges against bosses, which reward you with all cards from a small pool, the latter allows you to buy packs, which grant 5 cards from a large pool. Old gods is an expansion just like GvG, yes, it consists entirely of the cards.

Both of these have been retired, as the new Standard Format only allows you to use cards released in the last 2 years, i.e. in 2016 you can use cards from 2015 and 2016. So neither Naxx nor GvG is available for purchase anymore. Nor are they free, they are completely unavilable. Once 2017 hits, League of Explorers, Grand tournament and Blackrock Mountain share the same fate.

Yes, you can still use the cards in the wild format, but this is not the focus of play anymore. You are still able to craft all the cards from GvG and Naxx though, if you really want to use them.

Comment: Side note: The adventure Naxxramas can still be unlocked for coins on the Mobile version of Hearthstone. I'm not by a PC to confirm if this is available on the main version too. - It looks like you can still "buy" the adventure, but not with real cash. (Gold only).  Besides that, you're correct in that these cards and GvG are not supported anymore in Standard play.

Comment: @NBN-Alex Thanks for the info. There is no option in the PC version to buy (with money or with gold) that adventure, neither in the online Battle.net shop, that adventure is not listed.

Comment: @ElektroStudios On the home screen of Hearthstone, choose the "Solo Adventures" button. There, you should be able to purchase any of the adventures (Curse of Naxxramas, Blackrock Mountain, and League of Explorers).

Comment: @ken.ganong As I said, those adventures are not listed in-game to purchase them (are not visible in-game shop neither after pressing the solo-adventures button), neither in the online Battle.net shop. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @NBN-Alex if an account owned at least one wing of the adventure before it was retired, that account will continue to have the option to buy the remaining wings with gold.  An account that has not bought at least one wing will no longer have the option to buy any wing by any method.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, they are removed because **they have gone *wild***. *Whispers of the Old Gods* introduced *standard* battles which allow non-core boosters and adventures up to one year before the season year. The oldest card pack you can use in the standard is *The Grand Tournament*, and the oldest adventure is *Blackrock Mountain*. So you don't have to worry about *Goblin vs. Gnome* owners having an unfair advantage against you with old cards. Screw you, Dr. Boom!
2. It is "free" in terms of you can play with people who own *Whispers of the Old Gods* packs, sure. However, unless you have obtained the packs for free by some means, you have to pay for the booster packs as usual.

Comment: I believe "Dr. 7" or "Dr. Broken" is the correct term

Comment: @ws04 "Dr. Balance" actually came up to my mind, but I decided to go serious and wrote his *canonical* name instead.